# Why the url of an hyperlink (image) appears in mail signature

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, html-email, signature

Here is my problem :

When my colleagues receive my email including an html signature, on one of the clickable icons (image with hypertext link) the url appears next to the image, between square brackets [ ... ].

I don't understand where the problem comes from. Especially since the problem only appears on one of the images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOc4x.png)

Another problem, my signed email systematically ends up in the recipient's spam! How to prevent this? It's very problematic if all the emails I send end up in spam.

Perhaps it is precisely the fact that the email is considered spam that disturbs the display of the clickable icon?

My code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no" />
        <title>Signature</title>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:AllowPNG/>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if (mso)|(mso 16)]>
        <style type="text/css">
        body, table, td, a, span { font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Trebuchet, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; }
        a {text-decoration: none; color: #0066B1;}
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
    
    <style>
    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: #0066B1 !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
}
    u + #body a {
            color: #0066B1 !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
}
     
    #MessageViewBody a {
            color: #0066B1 !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
}
        
  a, a:link, a:visited { text-decoration: none !important; color: #0066B1; }     

    body, table, td, a, span { font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Trebuchet, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; }
    a {text-decoration: none; color: #0066B1;}
        
    </style>
        
        
</head>
    
    <body id="body" style="font-family:'Arial','Tahoma','Trebuchet','Helvetica','sans-serif'">
        
        <table role="presentation" style="padding-left: 8px ; border-spacing:0px">

                <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing:0px ; height: auto">
                <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; border-spacing:0px ; padding-top: 4px">
                    <img 
                    src="https://i.postimg.cc/CxnvTpVJ/logo.png"
                    alt="[LOGO]"
                    title="Logo"
                    width="208"
                    style="width:208px">
                </td>
                
                 <td style="width: 15px ; padding:0px ; margin:0px; border-spacing:0px">&nbsp;</td>
                    
                 <td style="padding: 0px ; text-align: left ; line-height: 1.3 ; font-size: 10pt; border-spacing:0px ; vertical-align: top ; font-family:'Arial','Tahoma','Trebuchet','Helvetica','sans-serif'">
                        <b>Henri Dupont</b>
                        <br/> 
                        Directeur d'agence
                        <br/> 
                 </td>
                
            </tr>
           
            <tr style="border-collapse: collapse">    
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="vertical-align: bottom">
                    <a style="text-decoration: none !important" href="https://qrco.de/">
                    <img
                    src="https://i.postimg.cc/jdT6nkhw/add-contact.png" 
                    alt="contact"
                    title="Ajouter aux contacts"
                    width="23"
                    style="width:23px ; text-decoration: none !important ; margin-right: 3px">
                    </a> 

                    <a style="text-decoration: none !important" href="https://qrco.de/">
                    <img 
                    src="https://i.postimg.cc/QMghCCNW/web.png" 
                    alt="site"
                    title="Site internet"
                    width="23"
                    style="width:23px ; text-decoration: none !important ; margin-right: 3px">
                    </a> 

                    <a style="text-decoration: none !important" href="https://qrco.de/">
                    <img 
                 src="https://i.postimg.cc/PfQp9fmJ/linkedin.png" 
                    alt="linkedin"
                    title="Linkedin"
                    width="23"
                    style="width:23px ; text-decoration: none !important ; margin-right: 3px">
                    </a> 

                    <a style="text-decoration: none !important" href="https://qrco.de/">
                    <img 
                src="https://i.postimg.cc/SRh98JcF/facebook.png" 
                    alt="facebook"
                    title="Facebook"
                    width="23"
                    style="width:23px ; text-decoration: none !important ; margin-right: 3px">
                    </a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing:0px ; height: 10px"></tr>
            
            <tr style="border-collapse: collapse">
                
                <td style="padding: 0px ; margin: 0px ; line-height: 1.3; font-size: 9pt; border-spacing:0px; text-align: right ; vertical-align: top ; font-family:'Arial','Tahoma','Trebuchet','Helvetica','sans-serif'">
                    <b>Agence Sud-Ouest</b>
                    <br/> 
                    Pôle d’Activités 
                    <br/>
                    43, avenue Victor Hugo
                    <br/> 
                    47000 Villefranche
                        
                 </td>

                 <td style="width: 15px ; padding:0px ; margin:0px; border-spacing:0px"></td>


                <td style="font-size: 10pt; margin:0px; border-spacing:0px ; border-collapse: collapse ; vertical-align: top ; font-family:'Arial','Tahoma','Trebuchet','Helvetica','sans-serif'" >
                    
                    <a title= "Téléphoner" href="tel:+33600000000" style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #0066B1 !important">+33(0) 7 00 00 00 00</a>

                <br/>
                    
                    <a style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #0066B1 !important; line-height: 2.1" title= "Téléphoner" href="tel:+33600000000">+33(0) 2 00 00 00 00</a>

                <br/> 

    
                    <a style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #0066B1 !important" title= "Envoyer un mail"
                       href="mailto:bidule@mailer.de">bidule@mailer.de</a>
                <br/> 

            </tr>


        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer spam questions with a definitive answer, so SO doesn't allow them.

As to the square bracket, this can appear on Outlook.com when that client thinks the href link is invalid. Make sure the link is valid and working (and has http:// which it does)

Comment: Indeed the square bracket was here because i have delete a "/" by mistake in url ... Thank you.
However, I haven't found solution for the emails landing in the spam... :'(